# cgconfig.conf file is missing

Tags: configuration, cgroup

I installed cgroup on my ubuntu (13.9.0) using this command:

```
apt-get install cgroup-bin
```

However, cgconfig.conf file has not been created in /etc and not anywhere else. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3):

This configuration file can be created in 2 ways:

1. Copied from  `/usr/share/doc/cgroup-bin/examples/cgconfig.conf` and then appropriately edited
2. Semi-automatically generated by using `cgsnapshot`

**References:**

- Red Hat: [Generating the /etc/cgconfig.conf File](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cgsnapshot.html)
- Ubuntu Man Pages: [cgfonfig.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/cgconfig.conf.5.html)

Comment: It's worth to be noted that on debian systems, the `cgsnapshot` command expects an existing blacklist file, and it refuses to run unless it's available at `/etc/cgsnapshot_blacklist.conf`. At least these are my observations on Debian8/9.

Comment: `sudo touch /etc/cgsnapshot_blacklist.conf` seems to be enough to make Debian package happy to run `cgsnapshot`.

Comment: Ubuntu has the example files in `/usr/share/doc/cgroup-tools/examples/cgconfig.conf` because they renamed the package name in the past.